# Obtener Doctrine dentro de una entidiad de symfony4

Tags: php, api, symfony, doctrine2, symfony4

¿Como se puede obtener una instancia de Doctrine dentro de una entidad?

Si estoy en un controlador se que puedo obtener Doctrine de la siguiente manera:

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
```

El código sería algo así:

```
class ApiController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/users", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function users()
    {
        $doctine = $this->getDoctrine();

        /// ... Hacer cosas con doctrine
    }
};
```

Ahora tengo una entidad User, cada usuario tiene un trabajo, se ve algo así:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $job_id;

    // .... Otros campos y métodos
};
```

La cosa es que quiero obtener una instancia se Job con un método llamado getJob() dentro de la clase User

```
public function getJob()
{
    $doctrine = // ¿Como obtengo Doctrine aquí sin pasarlo como parámetro?

    return $doctine->getRepository(Job::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $this->job_id]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres que el campo $job_id obtenga el 'job' con el id que pases. Para esto, Doctrine te permite establecer un campo como [clave foránea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_for%C3%A1nea) a otra clase.

Esto es muy útil cuando quieres que dos tablas están conectadas mediante un campo (en tu caso, $job_id).

Entiendo que la lógica de tu base de datos es que un *User* solo puede tener un *job*, pero un *job* puede tener de *uno a muchos user*, es decir, la relación entre *User* y *Job* es [OneToMany](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html).

Para establecer la relación te quedaría algo así:

```html
<?php

class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Job", inversedBy="user"))
     */
    protected $job;
}
```

Con esto estamos diciendo dos cosas:

1. **targetEntity:** Entidad a la que hace referencia la relación ("Job").
2. **inversedBy:** Campo de la entidad *Job* que va a tener la relación con User ("user").

Acabamos de hacer la relación entre *User* y *Job*, ahora tenemos que hacer la relación inversa:

```html
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection

class Job
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|User[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="job")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

Nota que en la clase *Job* la relación es **OneToMany**, y en lugar de usar *inversedBy* se usa **mappedBy**.
Además de esto, establecemos el campo como un *Collection*, ya que hemos dicho que un Job puede tener muchos User.

Una vez que se añaden nuevos campos, se deben crear los *Getters* y *Setters* que se puede hacer con los siguientes comandos:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:NombreEntidad
```

Si usas Symfony 3.0 o mayor:

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:NombreEntidad
```

Si usas Symfony 4+:

```
bin/console make:entity --regenerate
```

Debes ejecutar este comando con las dos entidades.

Por último, tienes que grabar estos cambios en la base de datos con:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql    // comprobar SQL
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force       // ejecutar SQL
```

Comment: Efectivamente tenia que usar las relaciones ManyToOne y OneToMany que ofrece doctrine, Gracias!!!